# How do I get an uppercase ordinal to number with memoir class?

Tags: macros, memoir

The `memoir` class has a number of macros for converting a number to words. For example

```
 \numtotoname{113}
```

will print one hundred and thirteen.

Is there an equivalent macro for all caps?  Alternatively can one define one?

I am trying to define:

```
   \def\thechapter{\textsc{\numtoname{\@arabic\c@chapter}}}
```

This works,

```
   \textsc{\numtoname{\@arabic\c@chapter}},
```

but not this one:

```
   \def\chaptername{chapter}
   \def\thechapter{\textsc{\numtoname{\@arabic\c@chapter}}}
```

[image]

**Note:**

I am trying to convert chapter numbers to words. My guess is the answer probably need a number of `\expandafters`, which currently they evade me.

Comment: Do you mean "One Hundred and Thirteen" or "ONE HUNDRED AND THIRTEEN"? I guess the former, as the latter could be done either by `\MakeUppercase{}` or (somewhat?) by `\textsc{}`.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough I mean ONE HUNDRED AND THIRTEEN try it with `\MakeUppercase{}` :) Never thought `textsc`. This works will you please post the comment as an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough Sorry did not work in the real application.

Comment: There are a lot of variants. Maybe `\NumToName` does what you want?

Comment: @StephanLehmke No that is not what is needed (the missing one is the full caps, i.e, ONE HUNDRED...

Comment: Yep, I understand now.

Comment: @StephanLehmke Thanks, it probably need some sort of gigantic list of expandafters?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Unfortunately `\numtoname` uses `\n@me@number` which starts with `\numdigits` which is not expandable. So it won't work with any number of `\expandafter` tokens. One would have to define an "uppercase version" of `\n@me@number` with different versions of the `\nNamezzzz` macros. If you don't have a big number of chapters, the easiest way is to go with `\ifcase`

Comment: @egreg Thanks! I did use an `\ifcase` upto 70 and ended up with 110 sample chapters:), then discovered the memoir macros and thought life got easier...

Comment: There is an interesting insight about expandable macro programming hidden in here. Sometimes it seems moot trying to make an expandable macro by all means, even in contexts where no significant advantage in efficiency is to be gained. But here, with an expandable definition of `\n@me@number` it would have been super easy to define an all-upper-case version while the way things are it's almost impossible without a complete rewrite.

Comment: @StephanLehmke Very true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use `fmtcount`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\let\ordinal\relax % to avoid a spurious warning
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\NUMBERstring{chapter}}


\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{A}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can this be edited so that it appears like this in the ToC as well?

Comment: @KhalidHussain It already does; however you want to add `\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{\textbf{SEVEN }}}` before `\begin{document}` (use the wider number when written in words).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @KhalidHussain Please, open a fresh question with all details.

Comment: Okay. I've done that here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457007/uppercasing-chapter-number-in-words-in-toc-entry-memoir and it got an answer!

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`fmtcount` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount)'s `\NUMBERstring`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\usepackage{fmtcount}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\NUMBERstring{chapter}}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{112}
\chapter{A chapter}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: That crazy! ...but fair. :)

Comment: if you hover over the answered ... it gives the time:)

Answer (score 3):

How about this; perhaps a little more like typography and less like shouting (:-):

```
{\scshape \NumToName{#1}}
```

Comment: I would respectfully disagree with you on this one. Many a good book have the CHAPTER TWO, rather than CHAPTER 2, numbers don't always look on headings. It will also not look so good in Camel casing. I will post an image in the main post.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: I guess we'll just have to agree to differ, but don't forget the smiley. Oh, and of course, "Many a good book spells 'colour' without the 'u'"... (:->>>)