# Uppercasing chapter number (in words) in ToC entry (memoir)

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, memoir, chapters

I need the chapter numbers in capitalized words (i.e. in upper case). My MWE so far,

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\renewcommand{\cftchaptername}{Chapter\space}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}[1]{\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}}

\renewcommand{\chapternumberline}[1]{\MakeUppercase{\cftchaptername}\NumToName{#1}:\space}

% Failed attempt [1] using MakeUppercase
%\renewcommand{\chapternumberline}[1]{\MakeUppercase{\cftchaptername}\MakeUppercase{\NumToName{#1}}:\space}

% Failed attempt [2] using fmtcount
%\renewcommand{\chapternumberline}[1]{\MakeUppercase{\cftchaptername}\NUMBERstring{\NumToName{#1}}:\space}

% Failed attempt [3]
% Use with caution as it affects everything else:
% Figure nos., Table nos., Section nos., SubSection nos., etc.
%\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\NUMBERstring{chapter}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

I need the highlighted part in capital letters:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`memoir`](//ctan.org/pkg/memoir)'s `\numtoName` and `\NumToName` only capitalize the initial letter. Use [`fmtcount`](//ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount)'s `\NUMBERstringnum` instead:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{fmtcount}

\renewcommand{\cftchaptername}{Chapter\space}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}[1]{\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}}

\renewcommand{\chapternumberline}[1]{\MakeUppercase{\cftchaptername}\NUMBERstringnum{#1}:\space}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```